# Deleting a tree(data structure) in Python

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree

The following is deleting a Tree in C (provided by GeeksforGeeks)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* A binary tree node has data, pointer to left child 
   and a pointer to right child */
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int data) 
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)
                           malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;  
    return(node);
}

/*  This function traverses tree in post order to 
    to delete each and every node of the tree */
void deleteTree(struct node* node) 
{
    if (node == NULL) return;

    /* first delete both subtrees */
    deleteTree(node->left);
    deleteTree(node->right);

    /* then delete the node */
    printf("\n Deleting node: %d", node->data);
    free(node);
} 


/* Driver program to test deleteTree function*/   
int main()
{
    struct node *root = newNode(1); 
    root->left            = newNode(2);
    root->right          = newNode(3);
    root->left->left     = newNode(4);
    root->left->right   = newNode(5); 

    deleteTree(root);  
    root = NULL;

    printf("\n Tree deleted ");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
The above deleteTree() function deletes the tree, but doesn’t change root to NULL which may cause problems if the user of deleteTree() doesn’t change root to NULL and tires to access values using root pointer. We can modify the deleteTree() function to take reference to the root node so that this problem doesn’t occur. See the following code.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* A binary tree node has data, pointer to left child
   and a pointer to right child */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)
                           malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return(node);
}
```

Deleting a node in C can be done by `free(node)`. In Python, there's no such method. Do I need a reference to the node's parent to delete the node in Python whereas I don't need one in C?

(i.e., is there a way to do `delete(node)` instead of `parent.left = None` in Python?

**Clarification:**
I would remove a tree like following (there might be some errors) in Python.

```
def delete_tree(root, parent):
    if not root:
        return
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        if root is parent.left:
            parent.left = None
        else:
            parent.right = None
    delete_tree(root.left, root)
    delete_tree(root.right, root)
    root = None
```

In the provided C code, a node can be deleted by releasing the allocated memory for a specific node. In Python, however, I need a reference to the node's parent to delete the node. Is there a simpler way than my code to delete a specific node from a tree?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to accomplish:  Python uses garbage collection - there's never a need to explicitly free objects.  If you're done with a tree, its memory will be reclaimed automatically after the last reference to the tree goes away.

Comment: @TimPeters Is this true? Even implementing `__del__` and maybe having circular references?

Comment: Thanks @TimPeters. Could you look at the update? A more general version of my question would be actually "how do you delete a tree in Python?" but I wanted to address the difference between C's way of removing a node from a tree and Python's way of doing it.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: there is no way to *spell* "free this memory" in Python. The concept isn't part of the language. If there are circular references, garbage may not go away *immediately* after the last reference is lost, but my "after" didn't make any promise about how long ;-)  I don't know what you're getting at with `__del__`. It's just another method. If `__del__` creates a new reference to the object, then "the last reference" has *not* gone away - the object is no longer trash then.

Comment: @MaximusS, sorry, I still don't grasp what you're trying to accomplish. Python has neither `malloc()` nor `free()`. Forget they exist and you'll be happier ;-)  "How do you delete a tree in Python?" You don't. It will go away all by itself when your program stops referencing it. You can waste time ;-) setting stuff to `None` if you like, but it's not needed.

Comment: @TimPeters I was asking due to this from part of the doc: "A list of objects which the collector found to be unreachable but could not be freed (uncollectable objects). By default, this list contains only objects with __del__() methods.26.1Objects that have __del__() methods and are part of a reference cycle cause the entire reference cycle to be uncollectable, including objects not necessarily in the cycle but reachable only from it. Python doesn't collect such cycles automatically because, in general, it isn't possible for Python to guess a safe order in which to run the __del__() methods."

Comment: "You don't delete a tree in Python" is a great answer to my misleading question!

Comment: @Hyperboreus, yes `__del__` methods can create immortal circular trash. But they won't anymore in the next Python 3 release :-)

Comment: @TimPeters Now this is great news. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in comments, there's no need for this in Python.  But if you want Python code that "acts like" the C code, here you go:

```
class Node:
    # with data members .data, .left, and .right
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = self.right = None

def deleteTree(node):
    if node is not None:
        deleteTree(node.left)
        deleteTree(node.right)
        node.left = node.right = None
```

It is impossible to spell "free this memory" in Python.  All you can do - and all you need to do - is to stop referencing objects you no longer care about.

Edit:  and, I should add, you'll eventually think this is a **good** thing:  life is soooooo much more pleasant when you know you'll never see a `NULL` pointer dereferencing segfault again ;-)  And that's really "why" Python has no way to spell "free this memory".

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a little misunderstanding of differences in memory management in C and Python. In C language you're the one who need to delete all unused memory which was previously taken from the heap. You can do it by calling the `free` function.
Python uses [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) for automatic memory management. So, by doing `parent.left = None` you're telling: the reference to this object will be `None`, nobody else knows reference to this object, we can collect it. Garbage collector handles everything else, so you don't need to explicitly remove this object from heap.

> Is there a simpler way than my code to delete a specific node from a tree?

You're not deleting specific node from your tree, you delete the tree itself. You have easier approach to do that in Python - just set the reference to its root to `None` and garbage collector will take care about the tree.

Comment: Thank you aga. I understand what you're saying but it isn't what I intended to ask. Could you look at the update?

Comment: Hey Thank you! Now I realize that "delete a tree" question is only nontrivial in C and the problem is really not intended to do in Python

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is:

```
node ##class '__main__.node'
del(node)
node
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'node' is not defined
```